# Python 2 dimensional table and distinct entries

Tags: python, arrays

I'm making a function called `different()`. It needs to take a two-dimensional table as input and return the number of distinct entries in the table. I'm not sure how to start it,m I would really appreciate some suggestions. When used, it should look like this in the shell:

```
t = [[1,0,1], [0,1,0]]
different(t)
>>2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def different()-> int
''' takes a two-dimensional table and returns number of distinct entries'''
t = []
while 
#use set method?
```

Comment: Do you mean `0` and `1` are distinct, or `[1,0,1]` and `[0,1,0]` are distinct?

Answer (score 0):

```
def different(t):
    return len(set(tuple(item) for item in t))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible interpretations

```
>>> set(j for i in t for j in i)
set([0, 1])
```

and

```
>>> set(tuple(i) for i in t)   # equivalent to set(map(tuple, t))
set([(0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)])
```

Either way, different should return the `len` of the `set`

```
def different(t):
    return len(set(...))
```

If you like itertools, you can do the following

```
from itertools import chain
def different(t):
    return len(set(chain.from_iterable(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From basic knowledge of python you can solve the above problem

```
t = [[1,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,2,3], [1,0,1]]
a = []
for i in t:
    if i not in a:
        a.append(i)
print len(a)
```

you have created a new list name 'a' and you have inserted all those element in the list which are unique. And afetrwards you can get the length of the new list a.